# How to use Hashmap or Array to create a "list" of countries with attributes

Tags: processing, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize migration data using particle systems. Each row of the dataset contains: source country, destination country, year, and various amounts.
Each row should be represented as a particle system representing that data.

---

QUESTION:

What will be the best way to create a list of countries or country objects, with x,y location attributes and maybe some other attributes that could be added later?

Entire code for reference:

```java
// Based on Example Written by Casey Reas and Ben Fry
// Edited by Tom Bar-Gal



//particlesystem()
//addparticle()
//particle()



// ========== Table Data Stuff 

Table table;
int k = 0;
String[] destCountryArray = new String[0];
String[] sourceCountryArray = new String[0];

String destCountry = "";
String prevDestCountry = "";

String sourceCountry;

// ========


int maxParticles = 12000;

ParticleSystem ps;
ParticleSystem ps2;

int n = 0, n2=0;
int emmitMultiplyer = 1;
int emmitFreq = 1;
float particleSpeed = 0.002;

float locationX = 250;
float locationY = 450;

int[] sourceX = {10, 40, 200, 400, 700};
int[] destX = {300, 600, 300, 600, 600};
int[] amount = {10, 100, 500, 800, 1000};
int highestAmount = max(amount);

// a,b,c... max*a/{a+b+c...}

ParticleSystem[] PSystems;


void setup() {
  size(1200, 800);

  //=============== load table and create an array of countries

  table = loadTable("asylum_seekers.csv", "header");

  destCountryArray = (String[]) append(destCountryArray, "Israel");

  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    //println("going over row" + row.getString("Country / territory of asylum/residence"));
    String tempCountryHolder = row.getString("Country / territory of asylum/residence");
    //println("Got a temp country holder" + tempCountryHolder);
    boolean exists = countryExists(tempCountryHolder);
    if (exists==true) {
      //println("exists, skipping");
      continue;
    }
    println("Appending "+tempCountryHolder+" to list of length " +destCountryArray.length);
    destCountryArray = (String[]) append(destCountryArray, tempCountryHolder);
    println("destCountryArray length = "+ destCountryArray.length);
  }

  //============================

  PSystems = new ParticleSystem[destCountryArray.length];
  //frameRate(30);
  //colorMode(RGB,255,255,255,255);
  for (int i = 0; i<destCountryArray.length; i++) {

    // Particle Systems syntax = multiplyer, source, destination, amount);
    PSystems[i] = new ParticleSystem(1, new Vector3D(i*40+40, 100, 0), new Vector3D(i*40+40, 500, 0), 1/(i+1));
    //println("PSystems " + i + " is " +PSystems[i]);
  }

  //ps = new ParticleSystem(1, new Vector3D(width/2, height/2, 0));
  //ps2 = new ParticleSystem(1, new Vector3D(100, 200, 0));

  smooth();
}

void draw() {

  background(250);
  //ellipse(locationX, locationY, 5, 5);
  //ellipse(width/2, height/2, 5, 5);
  //ellipse(100, 200, 5, 5);
  //println(PSystems.length);

  for (int i = 0; i<destCountryArray.length; i++) {
    //println(PSystems[i]);
    PSystems[i].run();
  }


  for (int i = 0; i<emmitMultiplyer; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k<destCountryArray.length; k++) {
      if (frameCount % (k+1) == 0) {
        PSystems[k].addParticle();
        n++;
      }
    }
  }

  n2+=emmitMultiplyer;

  fill(0);
  text("Frame rate: "
    + int(frameRate), 10, 20);
  println(n);      
  println(n);
}




// ==============================//  A simple Particle class  // ===============================================//




class Particle {

  Vector3D loc;
  Vector3D des;
  Vector3D vel;
  Vector3D acc;
  Vector3D locHome, b, c;
  float relativeSpeed;

  float r;
  float timer;

  float t=0.0; 

  // Another constructor (the one we are using here)
  Particle(Vector3D l, Vector3D m) {

    //acc = new Vector3D(0,0.0005,0);  // particle acceleration

    acc = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0); //  new Vector3D(random(-0.1, 0.1), random(-0.02, 0), 0);
    loc = l.copy();
    des = m.copy();
    locHome = l.copy();
    locHome.x = locHome.x+random(-2, 2);
    locHome.y = locHome.y+random(-2, 2);
    des.x = des.x+random(-2, 2);
    des.y=des.y+random(-2, 2);
    relativeSpeed = random(0.5, 1.2);

    r = random(0.9, 2.3);  // particle radius
    timer = 10000.0;   // particles lifespan
    // * emmitMultiplyer = number of living

    b=new Vector3D(locHome.x+random(-20, 20), locHome.y+random(120, 180), 0);
    c=new Vector3D(des.x+random(-20, 30), des.y-random(120, 180), 0);
  }

  void run() {
    update();
    render();
  }

  // Method to update location
  void update() {

    if (t>=1)
      return;

    // https : // www.processing.org/reference/bezierPoint_.html

    loc.x = bezierPoint(locHome.x, b.x, c.x, des.x, t);
    loc.y = bezierPoint(locHome.y, b.y, c.y, des.y, t);

    t = lerp(t, 1, particleSpeed*relativeSpeed);
    //t+=particleSpeed*relativeSpeed; 

    // curvePoint(a, b, c, d, t)
    // vel.add(acc);
    // loc.add(vel);
    //timer -= 1.0;
  }

  // Method to display
  void render() {
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    noStroke();
    fill(70, 255);

    ellipse(loc.x, loc.y, r, r);
  }

  // Is the particle still useful?
  boolean dead() {
//    if (timer <= 0.0||t>=1.0) {
      if (t>=0.95) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}


// ==============================//  A ParticleSystem  // ===============================================// 



// A class to describe a group of Particles
// An ArrayList is used to manage the list of Particles
class ParticleSystem {

  ArrayList particles;    // An arraylist for all the particles
  Vector3D origin;        // An origin point for where particles are birthed
  Vector3D dest;
  int freq;

  //ParticleSystem( number of particles / frame, source, destination, frequency);
  ParticleSystem(int num, Vector3D v, Vector3D d, float f) {
    particles = new ArrayList();              // Initialize the arraylist
    origin = v.copy();     // Store the origin point
    dest = d.copy();

    //if (frameCount % (1/f) == 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      particles.add(new Particle(origin, dest));    // Add "num" amount of particles to the arraylist
    }
    //}
  }
  void run() {
    // Cycle through the ArrayList backwards b/c we are deleting
    for (int i = particles.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      Particle p = (Particle) particles.get(i);
      p.run();
      if (p.dead()) {
        particles.remove(i);
        n--;
      }
    }
  }

  void addParticle() {
    particles.add(new Particle(origin, dest));
  }

  //void addParticle(Particle p) {
  //  particles.add(p);
  //}

  // A method to test if the particle system still has particles
  boolean dead() {
    if (particles.isEmpty()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}


//=================================================== Class Country
public class Country {
  public float countryIndex;
  public float countryLocationX;
  public float countryLocationY;
  public float countryName;
}

// ================================================ Simple Vector3D Class
public class Vector3D {

  public float x;
  public float y;
  public float z;

  Vector3D(float x_, float y_, float z_) {
    x = x_; 
    y = y_; 
    z = z_;
  }

  Vector3D(float x_, float y_) {
    x = x_; 
    y = y_; 
    z = 0f;
  }

  Vector3D() {
    x = 0f; 
    y = 0f; 
    z = 0f;
  }

  void setX(float x_) {
    x = x_;
  }

  void setY(float y_) {
    y = y_;
  }

  void setZ(float z_) {
    z = z_;
  }

  void setXY(float x_, float y_) {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
  }

  void setXYZ(float x_, float y_, float z_) {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    z = z_;
  }

  void setXYZ(Vector3D v) {
    x = v.x;
    y = v.y;
    z = v.z;
  }

  public float magnitude() {
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
  }

  public Vector3D copy() {
    return new Vector3D(x, y, z);
  }

  public Vector3D copy(Vector3D v) {
    return new Vector3D(v.x, v.y, v.z);
  }

  public void add(Vector3D v) {
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    z += v.z;
  }

  public void sub(Vector3D v) {
    x -= v.x;
    y -= v.y;
    z -= v.z;
  }

  public void mult(float n) {
    x *= n;
    y *= n;
    z *= n;
  }

  public void div(float n) {
    x /= n;
    y /= n;
    z /= n;
  }

  public void normalize() {
    float m = magnitude();
    if (m > 0) {
      div(m);
    }
  }

  public void limit(float max) {
    if (magnitude() > max) {
      normalize();
      mult(max);
    }
  }

  public float heading2D() {
    float angle = (float) Math.atan2(-y, x);
    return -1*angle;
  }

  public Vector3D add(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2) {
    Vector3D v = new Vector3D(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z);
    return v;
  }

  public Vector3D sub(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2) {
    Vector3D v = new Vector3D(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y, v1.z - v2.z);
    return v;
  }

  public Vector3D div(Vector3D v1, float n) {
    Vector3D v = new Vector3D(v1.x/n, v1.y/n, v1.z/n);
    return v;
  }

  public Vector3D mult(Vector3D v1, float n) {
    Vector3D v = new Vector3D(v1.x*n, v1.y*n, v1.z*n);
    return v;
  }

  public float distance (Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2) {
    float dx = v1.x - v2.x;
    float dy = v1.y - v2.y;
    float dz = v1.z - v2.z;
    return (float) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
  }
}

boolean countryExists(String tempCountryHolder) {

  for (int i = 0; i < destCountryArray.length; i++) {
    //println("comparing '" +tempCountryHolder +"' with '"+destCountryArray[i] + "'");
    if (tempCountryHolder.equals(destCountryArray[i]) == true) {
      //println("found : "+ tempCountryHolder);
      return true; // it exists
    } //if
  } //for
  return false ; // not found
}//func
```

Answer (score 0):

answer was: hashmap of hashmaps

```
  HashMap<String, HashMap> countries = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
  for (int i=0; i<destCountryArray.length; i++) {

    HashMap<String, Float> country = new HashMap<String, Float>();

    countries.put(destCountryArray[i], country);

    country.put("x", i*20.0);
    country.put("y", i*40.0);
  }


for (Map.Entry me : countries.entrySet()) {
  print(me.getKey() + " is ");
  println(me.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use a nested `HashMap` like your answer suggests. You probably want to use your own class instead. Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Point> countries = new HashMap<String, Point>();
void setup(){
   countries.put("one", new Point(2, 3));
   countries.put("four", new Point(5, 6));
}

void draw(){
  Point pOne = countries.get("one");
  point(pOne.x, pOne.y);
}

class Point{
  float x;
  float y;
  public Point(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Or better yet, you could just use Processing's `PVector` class, which already represents points:

```
HashMap<String, PVector> countries = new HashMap<String, PVector>();
void setup(){
   countries.put("one", new PVector(2, 3));
   countries.put("four", new PVector(5, 6));
}

void draw(){
  PVector pOne = countries.get("one");
  point(pOne.x, pOne.y);
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/using-objects) is a tutorial on using classes, and [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating your own classes.